# Could not having formal research products affect my MPhil application?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, masters, curriculum

I graduated with a BS in Economics in the Dominican Republic. There are barely any local research opportunities there and I haven't been able to work on any as I've focused on my current job. My job involves research and analysis on a daily basis of international commodities market conditions, international economics and more. I have experience researching many topics with multiple tools, yet have not produced anything in a formal, academic format, since what I do is mainly oriented to upper management for decision making, so ends up primarily in PowerPoint presentations.

I have achieved great results at work thanks to my research and analysis, saving the company upwards of US$1MM, but I don't know how to use this to my advantage.

I want to apply for an MPhil in a program with an acceptance rate of 9% and think I have a strong profile for my application. Yet, as soon as I started drafting my Academic CV I got a rush of fear when I realized I don't have any formal written research products (which seems like a MUST) other than my undergrad thesis.

**Questions**

1. Could the absence of formal research hurt my application? Will I not seem like a good fit?
2. Is there any way I can use my work research and analysis to my advantage in my application?

Comment: Where do you want to apply? What country or countries? MPhil often implies UK.

Comment: Will it hurt your application? Perhaps. Can you do anything about that now? Not really. So, apply to a range of places and see what happens.

Comment: @Buffy, Oxford University, MPhil in Economics.
Background: 22y/o, 3 years of work experience, 3.86 GPA, good test scores.

Comment: Anyone's chances of getting into Oxford are very nearly zero, with a lot of highly qualified applicants. If you want a degree, make a broad search, not a narrow one, especially not an extremely narrow one to one of the world's top institutions.

Comment: Yes, I have that taken into consideration. I will be applying for other colleges as well. Regardless, it baffles me that publications are so heavily weighted in masters applications, what about the people like me who work for the private sector in manufacturing for example and want to study at a highly regarded college to acquire top of the line knowledge?

It just seems weird that I can't (I think) consider my research as work in my CV. Can I do so even if its not published?

Thank you for keeping in touch. @Buffy

Comment: Other colleges where? All UK or also US, etc? US is quite different. And do you eventually seek a doctorate?

Comment: Mostly in Europe, London School of Economics, Oxford, Cambridge, University of Edinburgh, Instituto Empresa (IE). Courses range from MPhil in Econ to MS in Econometrics and Mathematical Economics. I do intend to eventually seek a doctorate, yet not in the near future as I must go back to my country after the Masters - and need to further develop my professional career in my industry. @Buffy

Comment: I will be applying to other programs, yet, my main concern is in trying to find a way to show my research at work in my CV - as otherwise I would have to skip this section and loose the opportunity to show my research and analytical abilities. I have what I may consider a fairly strong profile for applications (99th percentile of Latin America in Bachelors in Business and Economics) - so I don't want to dismiss top universities and at least try. Can you or anyone else think of anything I can do? @JonCuster

Comment: @jhormazabal I have some doubts that your "research at work" can be considered research in the academic sense. You might want to look into the definition of "research", in particular into the definition applied by the respective universities.

Comment: This is what the department told me when I asked:

You’re research experience should be recorded within your CV and you are welcome to include you undergraduate thesis should you feel that it demonstrates considerable research experience. We generally leave it up to applicants to decide what exposure they wish to highlight.

@Buffy
Following this I think I can use my undergrad thesis with certainty, and maybe use very detailed investigations I conducted at work in my field. As this is research experience, yet without the result of a publication per say.

Thoughts?

Comment: @Roland please check my last comment, couldn't tag more than one user.